# TextEditor : Macros To Manipulate Strings

Tags: regex, macros, automation, text-editor

I often do some operations on set of string and generally I it works well with a regex in Notepad++. A long time ago I remember using some tool which could record an action and perform same operation. For example lets say I have this string . Please keep in mind this is just an example.

```
First Name,Last Name,Social Security
```

I want to convert it to the following:

```
first_name("First Name"),last_name("Last Name"),social_security("Social Security")
```

Is there any way to do this using some text editor? I have these type of requirements too often. I remember using vim for something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be accomplished using vim macros, but a "simple" substitution fits better

```
:s/\(^\|,\)\(\S\+\) \(\S\+\)\(,\|$\)/\l\2_\l\3("\2 \3")/g
```

Or you can use `awk` (`sed`, whatever) for this from within `vim`, like:

```
:%!awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} { print whatever you modified your columns }'
```

With macro, something like <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>l</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>

But this only partially works... (for the first column) Basically:

1. <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> records macro into `a` register
2. <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (assuming we are on the first char in the line, this yanks till the first `,`
3. <kbd>P</kbd> puts the yanked test right before the actual cursor position (that is the first char on the line)
4. (cursor position maintained) <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> inserts `("`, then leaves insert mode
5. <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> finds the next space and insert `")` *before*
6. <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> finds the second `space` backwards, and replaces with `_`
7. <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>~</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> moves to next char then change its case to lower, then moves to first char of line, and change that's case as well, then finally exit recording macro.

Then run your macro from normal mode via <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>.

Vim is very capable.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed vim allows you to do this kind of stuff. Using Vim Macro feature you can record and play a sequence of actions inside the editor. According to my experience it is very powerful, way more than in other text editors (As editing in vim by itself is based on sequences of commands. )
However, if you are not familiar with vim it will take time to learn how to use vim. But it will lead to efficient text editing and coding in the end.

There are a lot more advantages in using vim. There are lot's of articles on the internet explaining them as well. I suggest googling around a bit, so you can decide yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give a try with the java multiplatform free open source tool [jEdit](http://jedit.org/).

It provides macro recording and editing.

Macros are dumped / written in [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), which jEdit extends with a set of documented APIs that allows to achieve quite whatever you want through macros.

There are also many macros scripts shared by the [jEdit community](http://community.jedit.org/?q=filestore/browse/25).